Laravel Validation Rules If another field value greater then or equal to 15
I want to give a validation rule for card information:

required when number_of_guests field value is greater than or equal to 15
card_information will be required when number_of_guests field value is greater than or equal to 15

$rules = [
    'number_of_guests' => 'numeric|required|max:100',
    'card_information' => 'required_if:number_of_guests,>=15'
];


>=15 is an expression not a value ... is the input's value actually '>=15'? ... what version of Laravel are you using?

'required_if:number_of_guests,>=,15' // Corrected syntax

I'd use something like
$rules = [
    ...
];
if (number_of_guests >= 15) {
    // Add additional rules to $rules
}
// do validation

